# InfoPath 2013 Conversion to PDF or DOCX

Tags: sharepoint-designer, infopath, xslt, word, pdf

I have an InfoPath 2013 Form.  Once the form is completed, on Button click, I want to generate either a PDF or a Word Document.

I have done extensive research.  SP Designer Workflow works for SP2010 workflows. But I am on SP2013 and it is known that it does NOT work for SP2013.  I do not want to use SP2010 workflow.

Also, I do not want to purchase any 3rd party tools.  Does any one have any suggestions?  I have seen extracting the XML and creating XSLT might be the way to go, but that seems like a lot of coding to me and I am not experienced in this type of coding.

I would appreciate any and ALL suggestions.  THANKS!

Comment: If you don't want third party tools then you will need to write your own workflow manager action (a major undertaking) and a reliable InfoPath to PDF Converter, en even larger undertaking. There is good third party software available that matches all your requirements, see http://blog.muhimbi.com/2015/09/using-sharepoint-2013-workflow-manager.html (Full disclosure, I wrote that blog post)